# Why did classical musicians not name their pieces?

Tags: classical-music

For example, most of the [symphonies by Mozart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_symphonies_by_Wolfgang_Amadeus_Mozart) don't have names. Instead, they are called names like "Symphony no. 4 in D major", which sounds awfully bland. Today's composers all give their songs names, even if there're no lyrics. Why didn't Mozart give his pieces names?

I couldn't find anything on Google about this.

Comment: Why should they?

Comment: You say “awfully bland”, I say perfectly descriptive.

Comment: I think we should keep this one open as only one of the responses provides an answer to the substantive question. & that response is low down in the list.